# Use AppCompat v-7 library & Certain Modules of Support-v4 together (Version 24.2.0)

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am currently using appCompat library in one of the project with below dependency.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
}
```

Now as AppCompat library has an implicit dependency on the support-v4 library. I usually do not want to add any support-v4 dependencies.

But since the release of 24.2.0 version, support v-4 is divided into many modules such as `support-compat`, `support-core-utils`, `support-core-ui`, `support-media-compat`, and `support-fragment`

Obviously, I wants to only add certain module which my application is using so that I can reduce the overall method count and hence size of the application. But at the same time I also wants to use appcompat library which itself loading whole bunch of modules from v-4 library.

So, Is there something which I'm missing if I wants to use both Appcompat library and certain modules of v-4 library?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... `appcompat-v7` depends on `support-fragment` ... which depends on all of `support` modules ... obviously it implicates that whole `support-v4` is used if you are using  `appcompat-v7` (take a look at `appcompat-v7-24.2.0.pom`)